# DataTables - display special rows with differnent cells and formatting

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables, jquery-templates

We're using the jQuery [DataTables plug-in](http://datatables.net). The plug-in seems to be quite a bit unflexible. We've worked around 2 major issues already and are facing a 3rd now:

In our table we want to display a special row which is not an entity of the type all the others are. It serves as a visual separator between the rows above and the rows below. It has a different number of cells, a different format and a different content.

[image: Wireframe]

We're using jQuery templates to render the row contents in conjunction with the knockoutjs [binding handler by cognitive shift.](https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions) There seems not to be any way to customize different types of rows or anything in datatables, so cogshift overrides the `fnRowCallback` to support jQuery templates.

The way we're currently considering to solve this issue is by adding a "dummy" item to the viewmodel which has a special property, e.g. "IsDummy()" to determine how to render it. In the jQuery template we render the row differntly based on this property:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if IsDummy()}}
        <td colspan="5" style="background-color:yellow; text-align: center">
            Entries starting with ${StartLetter}
        </td>
    {{else}}
        <td>${Id}</td><td>${Name}</td>...
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

However this will break datatables at the latest when trying to sort, because it saves all td-s in a 1-dim array and relies on arithmetics to retrieve the right cell based on row and column number, or in short terms: All rows must have the same number of columns.

This is the point when I stopped and realized how awkward all these hacks are going to be and that there must be a better approach, or I might be missing a feature of datatables completely. - although I'm afraid that's not the case...

**Can anyone give me some guidance here?**

Update: In the meanwhile I found even more issues:

- If there aren't any "real" entries in the array, I want the datatable to display "no data found", i.e. I have to dynamically remove the dummy item if all other items are removed, and add it back once a new "real" entry is added.
- The summary of datatables says "Showing 6 of 6 entries" if there are 5 "real" entries because of the dummy entry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way late to the game, but there is support for a pseudo section header now: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: That's great! Sounds very promising, and since it is a piece of javascript we could even change it as much as we want to meet our requirements. Will try a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know colspan in datatables has problems. It wasn't supported and i don't if it is supported now, look at this [answer](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan/p1)

I've always used datatables and it always worked perfectly for me, but i don't think it's suitable for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely right. Just did another try where every row DID have the same number of columns (the special row merges 3 cells and later splits one into 3 to make up for the right number), but that in turn led to troubles in the header.

Comment: Do you know if there is any support for "special" rows or something like "section headers"?

Comment: @chiccodoro no idon't think there is support for that. There is support for extra data of a row ([here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)) and support for fixed and informational columns ([here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/counter_column.html)). You can use colspan in the `<thead>`

Answer (score 1):

I use the [row grouping plugin](http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) and it works better for me than the link in the answer because groups are preserved after sorting by a different column.